# 6*6 grid, with 1 person in 1 grid, in 1s each person moves to a grid adjacent to him, find the probability that after 1s all the grids have one person

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

I just encounter a question, when this is 5*5, it is impossible. (Chessboard)

Now I'm curious about what will happen if n is even, for example, 6*6.

> 6*6 grid, with 1 person in 1 grid, in 1s each person moves to a grid adjacent to him, with each possible movement equally likely, find the probability that after 1s all the grids have one person

I've attempted to solve some simple cases, but can not find any generalized method to count it.

Comment: Can the person move diagnoally?

Comment: Is it enough for you to start if you know that the number of ups and downs have to be the same and the number of lefts and rights have to be the same?

Comment: @TheLearner No they can't. Only up/down or left/right is elligible

Comment: @AndrewChin It sounds like a good start, but one can only move to an adjacent grid, rather than move to everywhere they want.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I assumed.  You will have $36$ moves consisting of (U)p, (D)own, (L)eft, and (R)ight, and in these $36$ moves, you must have the same number of U's as you do D's, and the same number of L's as you do R's.

Comment: On second thought, this condition is nowhere near enough to ensure you get what you want.

Comment: The probability isn't very high.  I ran a million simulations, with no successes.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer:** A set of movements having the desired property exists on an $\ n\times n\ $ grid if and only if $\ n\ $ is even. The movements must follow the edges of a set of disjoint $\text{"cycles"}^*$ of the graph of the grid.  Thus a set of such movements is possible if and only there exists such a set of disjoint cycles, the union of whose vertices contains all the vertices of the graph. Every cycle in the graph of a grid must contain an even number of vertices, so the total number of vertices must be even, which is only the case when $\ n\ $ is even.

Conversely, if $\ n=2r\ $ is even, then the union of the vertices of the disjoint $2$-cycles
$$
(2i-1,j)\rightarrow (2i,j)\rightarrow (2i-1,j)
$$
for $\ i=1,2,\dots, r, j=1,2,\dots,n\ $ includes all the vertices of the grid's graph.

The probability that a completely random set of movements will follow any given such set of cycles is
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{4n-8}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{(n-2)^2}\ ,
$$
so the probability of such a random set of movements having the desired property is
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{4n-8}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{(n-2)^2}C_n\ ,
$$
where $\ C_n\ $ is the number of ways that the graph of the grid can be decomposed into a set disjoint cycles whose vertices include every vertex of the grid's graph. I have no idea, however, whether there exists a convenient formula or algorithm for computing the value of $\ C_n\ $.

$\,^*$ By using the term "cycle" here, I mean to include walks of the form $\ \left(x_1,y_1\right)\rightarrow\left(x_2,y_2\right)\rightarrow\left(x_1,y_1\right)\ $ by following which two adjacent people would exchange places.  Such walks do not satisfy the usual definition of "cycle" in an undirected graph, because the edge $\ \left\{\left(x_1,y_1\right), \left(x_2,y_2\right)\right\}\ $ is repeated.

Comment: $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{4n-8}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{(n-2)^2}\ $ seems to be based on the assumption that each cycle can only be traversed in one direction.  Shouldn't it be multiplied by $2^k$ where $k$ is the number of cycles in the decomposition?

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8563/partition-a-graph-into-node-disjoint-cycles/8570#8570 I haven't quite been able to understand the answer yet, but it seems like you have to find all the perfect matchings in a larger graph.

Comment: I guess the answer isn't supposed to be self-contained.  You have to read [this paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/matching/Tutte-short-proof-of-factor-theorem.pdf) by Tutte.

Comment: I was assuming that a cycle and its reverse are two *different* cycles, so the factor of $\ 2^k\ $ you get by reversing every subset of the cycles in a set gets absorbed into $\ C_n\ $.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That makes sense.